# Money data type to store date values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking into some performance issues on a database that I have just inherited. I can see that there are a lot of implicit conversions because of queries casting money data type into date. It looks like almost all the date fields are having money data type.

Can someone tell me a good and valid reason as to why someone would use money data type for dates?

Thanks!

Comment: There is not good and valid reason. Only bad and invalid ones.

Answer (score 6):

There is absolutely no good and valid reason for this practice.

Both `datetime` and `money` are 8 bytes. `datetime` has 4 bytes reserved for the `date` and 4 for the `time`.

`money` has a range from `-922,337,203,685,477.5808` to `922,337,203,685,477.5807`. When casting from `money` to `datetime` the integer portion is treated as the number of days since `1900-01-01` and the fractional portion as the percent of the day.

This means that you lose precision in the `time` part (each `0.0001` increment = `8.640` seconds) and gain useless extra scale in the `date` part by being able to store numbers far too large to ever `cast` successfully to `datetime` (which has a maximum bound of `9999 AD`)

If possible fix the schema.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This confirms my suspicion. I guess this is not so easy to fix for an old system.

Answer (score 0):

I think only for space-saving and to have sub-minute granularity, but design is obviously **weird**

May be to avoid with this the DATETIME and SMALLDATETIME bounds, but if you say that it is often casting to date - it is not likely so.

**Update:**

Since as @Martin Smith said - it is not saving space - then design is much more weird.

One more suggestion - the data was imported from old legacy DB system, where datetime values were stored in such a way.

Obvoiusly - if you look for **good and valid reason** - there is **none**.

Comment: It won't save any space. `datetime` and `money` are both 8 bytes.